# Regex to filter string to find values ending with a given list of units

Tags: python, regex

I need to retrieve information from the following text:

```
"od 01. 01. 2015 do 28. 06. 2026 pevnú cenu elektriny pre stanovenie doplatku vo výške 387,65 eura/MWh, vyrobenej zo slnečnej energie v zariadení výrobcu elektriny s celkovým inštalovaným výkonom 4,82 kW, umiestnenom na streche Múzea"
```

From the above string, I need to find and return `4,82 kW`. The units could also be `MW` or `kWp`. I want to ignore the instance of `387,65 eura/MWh`.

I have tried using the following regex in Python:

```
matches = re.findall(r'\d+\,\d+\s', text)
```

but this returned `"387,65"`.

I need to capture not only the number but also units afterwards.

Comment: And why don't you match the desired substring at the end?

Comment: I don't know to write the right regex format.  In most cases I used, I received N/A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should work:

```
\d+\,\d+\s(?:MW|kWp|kW)
```

**Code:**

```
text = "od 01. 01. 2015 do 28. 06. 2026 pevnú cenu elektriny pre stanovenie doplatku vo výške 387,65 eura/MWh, vyrobenej zo slnečnej energie v zariadení výrobcu elektriny s celkovým inštalovaným výkonom 4,82 kW, umiestnenom na streche Múzea "

print(re.findall(r'\d+\,\d+\s(?:MW|kWp|kW)', text))
```

**Output:**

```
['4,82 kW']
```

If you want the decimal point (or in this case, decimal comma) to be optional, you can use:

```
\d+\,?\d+\s(?:MW|kWp|kW)
```